# Computing a fourth moment $E[Z^4] $

Tags: probability, integration, probability-theory, inequality

Suppose that $\epsilon_1,\ldots,\epsilon_n$ is a sequence of independent random variables, each taking the values $1,-1$ both with probability $1/2$. If $\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_n$ is a sequence of real numbers, define a random variable $Z$ and $\sigma\ge 0$ by,

$$Z = \sum_{k=1}^n\epsilon_k\alpha_k,\ \sigma^2 = \sum_{k=1}^n\alpha_k^2$$ so that $Z$ has mean zero and variance $\sigma^2$.

How can we show that

$$E[Z^4] \le 3\sigma^4$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $b_k=a_k\epsilon_k$. When you expand out
$$
Z^4=\left(\sum b_k\right)^4,
$$
you get terms like
$$
b_i^4,\quad b_i^2b_j^2,\quad b_i^3b_j,\quad b_i^2b_jb_k,\quad b_ib_jb_kb_\ell,
$$
where $i,j,k,\ell$ are distinct indices. The expectations of each of these (using the fact that the variables are independent with zero mean) are equal to
$$
a_i^4,\quad a_i^2a_j^2,\quad 0,\quad 0,\quad0.
$$
Therefore, 
$$
E[Z^4] = \sum_ia_i^4+3\sum_{i\neq j}a_i^2a_J^2\le 3\sum_{i,j}a_i^2a_j^2= 3(\sigma^2)^2
$$